# Get internal data of Scala Future **BEST CASE**

Tags: scala, async-await, future

**Hi**, I`m research about **Scala Future** and ways to get internal data is warped in *Future/Promises*.So I write all model I know about, to get internal data of Scala Futures.

Always we see this 2 case :

1- Some time we get *future internal data* inside a **block of async functions** like map, flatMap, foreach, fold , ...

2- Some time we get result inside of a Future like using **Await**

In this example I using `Akka` `?` or `ask` function (it`s async) and I try know **best practice** of how to get the result of future

1- out of block ?

2- in to block ?

- We know blocking is bad practice when we are async (so use `Await`, `Sleep`, ...) are bad.

please help me to find best practice replace `Await` or `Future.value.get.get`

**Tnx** !!!

here is my code example :

```
  //Main Problem
  val futureResult: Future[String] = (ping ? AskingTest).mapTo[String]

  //Solution number 1
  val awaitResult = Await.result(futureResult, myTimeout)
  println(s"(1): $awaitResult")

  //Solution number 2
  val eitherResult: Either[Throwable, String] = Await.ready(futureResult, myTimeout).value.get match {
  case Success(str) => println(s"(2): $str");Right(str)
  case Failure(err) => println(s"(2): $err");Left(err)
 }

  //Solution number 3 ***low speed***
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global 
  //BadPractice: Writ in play documentation.
  futureResult map { x: String =>
    println(s"(3): $x")
  }

  //Solution number 4
  futureResult.value.get match {
    case Success(str) => println(s"(4): $str")
    case Failure(err) => println(s"(4)$err")
  }

  //Solution number 5
  futureResult onComplete {
    case Success(str) => println(s"(5): $str")
    case Failure(err) => println(s"(5): $err")
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The best practice is to do a Await "at the end of the world". This means that you should combine all your futures in a single future and then Await only once.

```
val f1 = (ping1 ? AskingTest).mapTo[String]
val f2 = (ping2 ? AskingTest).mapTo[String]

val combinedFuture: Future[(String, String)] = for {
  str1 <- f1
  str2 <- f2
} yield (str1, str2)

// final await at the end of program
val (str1, str2) = Await.result(combinedFuture, Duration.Inf)
```

When I started to write code with Futures, I used to write Await at every line. which is wrong because it defeats the purpose of using Futures.

So your goal is to combine as many futures as possible using `for` and then Await only once.

The other solutions you have listed above are also OK except No 4 because it can lead to your program crashing if the future is not complete yet.

Comment: Tnx!!! , I think in combining Futures we must Wait for longest Future. so is bad practice, if we need to use await i think is best to use Await for each future.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned blocking is bad and you only should use it in testing.

Here is a nice Blog that describes the possibilities: [testing-future-objects-scalatest](https://lucianomolinari.com/2016/08/07/testing-future-objects-scalatest/)

In real life you should use for example this:

```
  futureResult.foreach { x: String =>
    // do some side effect
  }
```

All you have to make sure is that the process that calls this Future is not stopped (that is for example in a test the case)

Another solution is to use the Async - Await construct that has alos an implementation in Scala: [scala-async](https://github.com/scala/scala-async)

Comment: @kianjalali just switch it with `map`;). I used foreach as all your examples use `println` which is unit. I also added async-await construct - check it out.